# How can I sort these numerical strings in ascending order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I tried to sort an array using `.sort()`, but the output is not what I expected.

```
arr = ["0_11_6_comment", "0_3_6_comment", "0_5_4_comment"]
arr.sort();
```

Here is my expected output:

```
["0_3_6_comment", "0_5_4_comment", "0_11_6_comment"]
```

But I am getting this:

```
["0_11_6_comment", "0_3_6_comment", "0_5_4_comment"]
```

Comment: means you want to sort with 2nd interger values : 0_3_6_comment. 3<5<11 or something else?

Comment: well, you sort it because the 2nd integer value 1<3<5, so it will not change the order by using arr.sort.

Comment: I don't know what you are actually trying to do since we are still waiting for additional informations, but I guess you're aware that the accepted answer is not able to sort such an array : `["0_1_3_comment", "0_1_1_comment", "0_1_2_comment"]`. Next time, feel free to [reply to comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872339/sort-in-ascending-order-using-javascript?answertab=votes#comment33115612_21872339) in order to help folks to provide a better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to sort based on 2nd integer value. use this:

```
var arr = ["0_11_6_comment", "0_3_6_comment", "0_5_4_comment"];
alert(arr);
arr = arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    return parseFloat(a.split("_")[1]) - parseFloat(b.split("_")[1]) 
});
alert(arr);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nL7d2/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The array is sorting, though it's sorting in lexicographic order, not numerical, and that's probably not what you want. If you want to change how the `sort()` method sorts, you need to provide your own definition of what "sorting" means. Do this by passing a comparison function as a parameter.

See here for more details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
a.sort(function (a, b) {
    // '1_2_3_comment'.split('_')
    // gives ["1", "2", "3", "comment"]
    a = a.split('_');
    b = b.split('_');
    // if a[i] - b[i] = 0 then check next
    return a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1] || a[2] - b[2];
});
```

Read : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort.

Answer (score 0):

### [Here's a JSFiddle with the answer](http://jsfiddle.net/9qf9Y/2/)

I suggest reading [**this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
ary.sort(function (a, b) {
  return getSecondInteger(a) > getSecondInteger(b) ? 1 : -1;
});

function getSecondInteger (str) {
  return Number(str.split('_')[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var arr = ["0_11_6_comment", "0_3_6_comment", "0_5_4_comment", "1_2_3_comment"];
arr.sort(function(a, b){
  a = a.match(/\d+/g);
  b = b.match(/\d+/g);
  return a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1] || a[2] - b[2];
});

console.log(arr)
// result is ["0_3_6_comment", "0_5_4_comment", "0_11_6_comment", "1_2_3"]
```

Try [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5whES/1)

Comment: Two times slower than [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21872440/1636522) : http://jsperf.com/q-21872339-1636522. Then, your regular expression could be shorter : `/\d+/g` ;)